# How can I get values in a PHP array?

Tags: php

I want to get some values from an array in PHP. I use *[print_r](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)* for debugging, and my array content is:

> Array ( [54.38.202.159:20756] => Array ( [dedicated] => 1 [gamename] => mta [gametype] => MTA:SA [gq_address] => 54.38.202.159 [gq_dedicated] => 1 [gq_gametype] => MTA:SA [gq_hostname] => MTA @ ServerProject.eu [gq_joinlink] => mtasa://54.38.202.159:20756/ [gq_mapname] => None [gq_maxplayers] => 20 [gq_mod] => [gq_name] => Multi Theft Auto [gq_numplayers] => 0 [gq_online] => 1 [gq_password] => 1 [gq_port_client] => 20756 [gq_port_query] => 20879 [gq_protocol] => ase [gq_transport] => udp [gq_type] => mta [map] => None [max_players] => 20 [num_players] => 0 [password] => 1 [players] => Array ( ) [port] => 20756 [servername] => MTA @ ServerProject.eu [teams] => Array ( ) [version] => 1.5 ) )

How can I access some value from this array? For example, I want a "num_players" value. I was trying to use:

```php
$data["num_players"]
```

But this gives me an error:

> Notice: Undefined index: num_players

Comment: It should be `$data['54.38.202.159:20756']['num_players']`

Comment: Follow the structure. `"num_players"` is not at the top level. `54.38.202.159:20756` is. A little tip for the future: use `var_dump` over `print_r`. It has more detailed information and display the structure in a more user-friendly way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is multidimensional, and the first dimension seems to be the [IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) of the server.

If that IP address is fixed, you can use the answer of @B001ᛦ in the first comment to your question.

Otherwise, if it changes and if there can be multiple IP addresses, you can just loop.

```
foreach($data as $ip => $info) {
    echo $info['num_players'];
}
```